# A removeable adhesive, that sticks to metal to metal or metal to plastic, any suggestions?

Tags: adhesive, metal

I have a problem where I want to remove a pressed metal part, to be more specific the brake arm of a SRAM S7.

I would like to make a hollow cup like jig, where I put a thread inside to pull out the brake arm evenly without running the risk of bending it.
I plan to make that cup either by investment casting an aluminium part, or try to use a 3D printed piece directly, though I'm not sure if it would be able to withstand the pull forces.

Either way, I need to way to temporarly secure the jig to the surface, and then remove it again, preferably in a way that lets me repeat that process indefinetly.

The surface of the metal part is a bit rough and made out of presumably stainless steel.

The glue has to be able to resist tension, shear doesnt matter.

I researched a bit, but wasn't able to come to a satisfactory conclusion.
Hot glue would be able to be removed without a trace, but it doesn't stick to metals.

Super glue would probably not be able to bridge the gaps of the rough surface of the brake arm.

And JB-Weld wouldn't be able to be easily removed from what I can tell.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I could do this?

PS: I don't want to drill holes and tap screws since that would partly destroy the part.

Comment: This might be better for https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/  .I would only only trust a removable adhesive for primary fitting up.  Even JB-weld I would not trust  on something I might need to stop smashing my head into something hard.  I would want bolts/welds to hold it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs in https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is not a jig that would be on the bicycle during riding, I'm trying to extract a metal piece that's pretty much outside the scope of normal bicycle mechanics and more inline with this stack.

Comment: How much force do you expect the adhesive to hold?  Removable adhesives usually are limited to the force they will hold, usually quite low(~50 pounds or less safe).

Comment: What's an SRAM S7? A picture of the part you're trying to remove would go a long way for possible alternatives. Sounds like you're trying to make a gear puller of sorts.

Comment: It's an internal gear hub, in my case with a coaster brake. The brake has a reaction arm that's press fitted into the end cap, I'd like to remove it since it's dead weight, ever since I reconfigured the internals to freewheeling, that's why I like to remove it.


The more the adhesive can hold the better, as long as it's removable. It should be about as strong as some of the generic duct tapes on the market, preferably stronger. But I'm not sure what type of adhesive would fit my use case here.

Comment: Did some Googling and found this maintenance manual: https://www.avantum.bike/downloads/sram_s7_2010.pdf I think I see the arm you're looking at. Are you trying to save the part or just remove it?

Comment: @spuck I'm trying to remove it without bending or breaking it, just in case I change my mind and want to restore the brake. I could tap a few screw into it and have something to pull on, but that would partialy destroy the part. So I'm looking into removable glues.
On page 72, part 2, you can clearly see how it holds the rotational forces by the star shape, and isnt really subjected to tensile forces, so it's pressed in.

Comment: @HubShakerCentral - see the banner at the top of the page. This stack is for DIY **Home Improvement**, not DIY Anything & Everything. Your question has nothing to do with Home Improvement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the glues you mentioned, I would use the JB Weld and then use a heat gun to remove it. That's *if* JB Weld actually sticks to the metal. You mention it's stainless steel; it could also be zinc galvanized steel. I'm assuming it's a very smooth surface, which is sometimes difficult to glue.

**EDIT**:

From JB Weld's [website](https://www.jbweld.com/faqs):

> HOW CAN I REMOVE J-B WELD PRODUCTS FROM HANDS/SKIN OR SURFACES?
>
> Acetone or acetone-based products will remove most J-B Weld from hands
> and most surfaces. In some instances, a light to moderate abrasive
> might be required.
>
> When fully cured, some J-B Weld products can only be removed by
> grinding or filing it off, or by directly heating the product above
> the 600º maximum temperature threshold.

Comment: It's actualy a coarse surface, almost like a casting.
I wasn't aware that JB-Weld is removable by using heat, so I think I'll try it that way.
Thank you for your suggestions!